# Change top view from nested view AngularJS UI-Routing

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

i am kinda new to this UI-Routing concept, so i was wondering the following.

Is it possible to change a top view from within a nested one.
So we start at index and call Account state within that view i call the Account.login view by using:

```
<a ui-sref="Account.login"></a>
```

Now is it possible to call the Index state again from **within** Account.login view and how would one accomplish that.

```
        .state('Home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "pages/Home.html",
        })
        .state('Account', {
            url: "/profile",
            templateUrl: "pages/Account.html"
        })
        .state('Account.login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "pages/Account_Login.html"
        })
        .state('Account.register', {
            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "pages/Account_Register.html"
        })
```

Working with Ionic Framework.

Main Page:

```
       <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="custom_Header">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" style="background-color:#4D8693"></button>
            </div>

            <h1 class="title"><a ui-sref="Home" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="img/Header.png" /></a></h1>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-gear-b" style="background-color:#4D8693"></button>
            </div>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="has-header">
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-content>
```

Account.html:

```
<div class="has-header">
    <a ui-sref="Home">
        <img src="img/test.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

If i now press on that image on Account view, it will return me to my main page but without my buttons in the header, the image in the middle is still there.

Including: http://play.ionic.io/app/2f5cc1913037

Comment: within Account.login view: <a ui-sref="Index">Index</a>

Comment: Yes but for some reason when i do that, my buttons/icons who should be in the header dissapears, the rest loads though.

Comment: Done. Updated the templates.

Comment: Change ui-sref="Home" to ui-sref="Index"

Comment: Oh woops, the app.JS wasn't updated on this page. I changed index to home.

Comment: try cange state Home url from '/' to ''

Comment: or/and add <base href="/"> to header

Comment: also set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: Unfortunatly did it not solve my problems buttons are still dissapearing.

Comment: work fine http://play.ionic.io/app/058bc0a92cc9

Comment: with nested states: http://play.ionic.io/app/1bbf16c32731

Comment: Here is mine http://play.ionic.io/app/397252dc79ed